# Presenting of CNContactViewController forUnknownContact breaks view controller hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, cncontactviewcontroller

This code collapses all of my UIViewController hierarchy

```
func openVCard(for cnContact: CNContact) {
        let contactViewController = CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact: cnContact)
        contactViewController.contactStore = CNContactStore()
        contactViewController.delegate = self

        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: contactViewController)
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Close", style: .done, target: nil, action: nil)
        let flexibleSpaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        contactViewController.setToolbarItems([flexibleSpaceButton, doneButton, flexibleSpaceButton], animated: false)

        navigationController.isToolbarHidden = false
        contactViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = []

        present(viewController: navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

but it seems ok for `CNContactViewController(forNewContact`

Is it an Apple bug?

Comment: let contactViewController = CNContactViewController(for: cnContact). Other lines are similar, works for me. iOS15. By the way, contactViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = [] helps me resolve the avatar's top cut issue. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should push **CNContactViewController** instead of present.
I suggest you to watch WWDC 2015 presentation about this issue.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/223/

After 30:00 you can see demo about this issue.